# Error in downloading the .ipa file in AdHoc distribution

Tags: iphone, ios, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

i am trying to install an app from the server having .ipa and .plist. when i try to call the url

i am getting unsupported url, with error code 1002, what should i do. how to call this url.

```
NSLog(@"requestString : %@",requestString);
self.responseData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:loginCredentials forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];    
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
[cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Comment: <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http:/oursite.com/myApp.plist" id="text">

Comment: the above url is the format which i try to call. please help me in this.

Comment: Can anyone give us sample code for this.

Comment: `<a href=" ... >` - that is a *HTML* element, not a URL. It *contains* a URL, so would have to extract that first. - Are you trying to install another app from within your iPhone app? That cannot work due to sandboxing.

Comment: yes, i am trying to install another app from my iPhone, i am trying to call that URL from safari browser, app starts downloading, but from my app its throwing error. what should i do, provide me any sample format for hitting this URL.

Comment: i am hitting "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=down‌​load-manifest&url=http:/oursite.com/myApp.plist"

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the below format to get it work.

```
<a class="correct button" href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://baseURL/app.plist">Distribution Link</a>
```

And the contents of plist is structured as shown below:

[image: PLIST]

Access:

```
self.responseData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                            requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:loginCredentials forHTTPHeaderField:@"Auth"];    

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request   delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
webView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]]];
```

hi, i used the above format to request for the URL and i got the alert asking for install and cancel, now its working fine.

Request URL:

"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http:/oursite.com/myApp.plist" id="text"